# Accessing InheritedWidget data in initState

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm confused about the relationship between "Widgets" in the widget tree, and "Classes" that do not render in the Widget tree.

### Context

I have a class called `Api` that is responsible for making various API calls. This class needs a "Token" to make authenticated requests, which it needs to be initialized with:

```
class Api {
  static const BASEURL = "https://api.google.com";

  final String token;
  Api({this.token});
  ...
```

The Token is retrieved from `SharedPreferences` once, when the application first loads. I wasn't sure how to do this using a "class", so I opted to use a Widget instead like so:

```
// main.dart
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: TokenProvider(
          token: "some_token", // will be loaded from SharedPreferences
          child: MainScreen()
        ),
    )
  }
}
```

### Problem

When I want to access the API in MainScreen (or any of the other descendant screens), I'd have to retrieve the token first.

I tried doing it like so:

```
  // main_screen.dart
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    final token = context
        .ancestorInheritedElementForWidgetOfExactType(TokenProvider)
        ?.widget;
```

..but this returns a "Widget", not the token. I tried doing `?.widget.token` but I get this error message:

> Error: The getter 'token' isn't defined for the class 'InheritedWidget'. Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'token'.

--
I feel like I'm fighting with the framework instead of letting it guide me. What's a better way to do this?

Comment: first of all, don't call ancestorInheritedElementForWidgetOfExactType  from initState, you nee to use didChangeDependencies() instead. Another thing is ancestorInheritedElementForWidgetOfExactType  is deprecated and you need to use dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType. https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/BuildContext/dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType.html

Comment: you may try Provider package as it uses widgets for handling everything.

Comment: I'm assuming that TokenProvider is a provider that you've created? (otherwise, I couldn't find any reference to it) Darish is correct, this would be a perfect place to use a provider, and then use Provider.of<ProviderToken>(context).VariableThatYouNeed to listen to the variable when 'notifyListeners()' is called in the Provider.

Comment: @William yes TokenProvider is a class I created. Would this Provider.of() call work inside initState? I ask because thats where I make the API call now

Comment: The Provider.of() call can be used inside the widget itself. This is part of the Provider package, and is updated whenever "notifyListeners()" is run inside of you TokenProvider class. Therefore, you shouldn't need to use it inside initState().  A good read would be: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple#accessing-the-state  (the Provider section starts about halfway through the "accessing the state" section)

Comment: @WilliamTerrill thanks for the link! I've gone through it and can see how this would work. However, the issue is that I'm making an API call directly *after* the token is retrieved, e.g. `Api(token: token).getItems()` which is async and returns a future. Handling this in `initState` kept the Widget tree cleaner. Is using `FutureBuilder` within the Widget tree the way to go with `Consumer<TokenProvider>`, or is there a better way?

Comment: That is one way to do it,yes. Another would be to have all of the token and getItem calls inside of the provider itself, and have the widget tree change based on the results of some kind of Boolean.For example you could have the variable bool receivedItems that is set in the provider and the widget returned in the page would have something like Provider.of<TokenProvider>(context).receivedItems ? DoneWidget : WaitingWidget  (that translates to “If receivedItems is true, show a widget that uses that information, or else show a widget that means you’re waiting,